# Tanget plane of an image

Tags: transformations, image-processing, computational-geometry, geometry, image

My problem is about tangent plane. I have an image (m by n). I obtain surface normal vector using machine learning methods. Then i would like to obtain tangent plane for this surface normal.

To imagine my problem, you can look this paper; [Surface Normals in the Wild](https://arxiv.org/abs/1704.02956). In this paper, authors find surface normal and draw/find virtual tangent plane around this point (Figure 4 in above paper).

For this problem, i have really no idea. Any tips or starter idea will be acceptable.

Thank you

Comment: What are you planning to use the tangent plane for? Texturing?

Comment: Does [this Mathematics Stack Exchange answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/752252/find-plane-by-normal-and-instance-point-distance-between-origin-and-plane) provide enough information?

Comment: @Noah Witherspoon, i will embed an image into this tangent plane. (So it will look like so natural)

Comment: @user1118321, i will look and test that question immediately. I hope it will work. I will feedback about it. Thanks